# Complex django query, getting objects whose foreignkey_set does not contain an object that satisfies a restriction

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-q

I have a model, `foo`, and a model `bar`. `bar` has a foreignkey to `foo`, as well as a `days` field, which is a postgresql DateRangeField

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    baz = models.CharField()

class bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    days = DateRangeField()
```

I need to do a query, given a date (`day`), and a `baz`: get all Foo objects that satisfy baz = `baz`, and that **do not** have an associated `bar` object that satisfies `days.lower < days < days.upper` (or in other words, do not have `day` within the range of their `days` variable.

I've looked at Q queries, but the only way I've found to do it so far is to get all `Foo` objects that satisfy `baz=baz` and then use python to do the rest of it (which is clearly inefficient in terms of DB queries).

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: @ArpitSvt version >2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but it seems like you should simply do:

```
Foo.objects.filter(baz=baz).exclude(bar__days__contains=day)
```

Comment: That would work, except that Foo doesn't have a `bar` field. Bar has a foreignkey to foo

Comment: That doesn't matter, Django supports [querying across reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). Perhaps you should show your real models, and the error you get.

Comment: I didn't realise. I thought reverse relationships requires `select_related()` or similar. That works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DateRange` from `psycopg2.extras` function. Here is an example of that, [link](https://medium.com/@jayakrishnandamodaran/querying-django-postgresql-daterange-field-f61bcd6872e9)

Comment: Yes, but I need to follow the related key first, something like this (but this doesn't work, as the second filter is trying to filter on Foo, rather than Bar):
`Foo.objects.filter(baz=baz).select_related("bar").filter(days__contains=day)`